# <a> click="" does not works with tabindex='0'

Tags: html, angular, click

Here's my code.

The click works without tabindex but when i add tabindex='0' and hit enter when the element is focused, it doesn’t works.

<a type='button' role='button' class='primary-link' tabindex='0' (click)='callMe()'>Call me

Answer (score 1):

1-You should use (onclick) not (click), use (onclick) without brackets.
2-add the closing tag.

```html
<a type='button' role='button' class='primary-link' tabindex='0' onclick='callMe()'>Call me</a>
```

3- it's better to use button tag.

```html
<button class='primary-link' tabindex='0' onclick='callMe()'>Call me</button>
```

Comment: Sorry Ramy, but this is fundamentally wrong in the context of an Angular application.